# Jmeter post multipart form data with string

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jmeter, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload file with string in JMeter. It doesn't work

```
POST http://localhost:8080/upload

POST data:
--v2IM1VsVLV5EbtspRzGOSrHaDQb-mlef6r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{   "name": "John",  "country": "US" }

--v2IM1VsVLV5EbtspRzGOSrHaDQb-mlef6r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--v2IM1VsVLV5EbtspRzGOSrHaDQb-mlef6r--


[no cookies]
```

I got the following error using JMeter

```
{"code":"ERROR","message":"Required request parameter 'input' for method parameter type String is not present"}
```

I am able to hit the request using curl or Postman without any issues. Here is my curl request.

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
   -F "file=@\"./sample.txt\";type=text/plain;filename=\"sample.txt\"" \
   -F "input={   \"name\": \"John\",  \"country\": "US" }" \
 'http://localhost:8080/upload'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to execute the request successfully using Postman you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy

   [image]
3. Copy the `sample.txt` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will capture the request and generated proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)